Joining domain via Ansible returns error "Already joined to this domain" while via shell is OK
I'm getting a strange message with Ansible.
On a RHEL 9 server, I can join our domain via the shell command line
realm join example.xyz --user=svc-ansible --computer-ou="OU=Linux Servers, OU=Servers, OU=ACME, OU=Units, DC=example, DC=xyz"

Once done that I can successfully change user via su - johndoe@example.xyz, where "johndoe" is an user defined in the AD and belonging to an AD group defined in simple_allow_groups in the file /etc/sssd/sssd.conf.  So the config seems to be working.
After that, I run an realm leave example.xyz --remove -U 'svc-ansible' and realm list beforehand to check that the server is not in the domain anymore.
However, when I run via AWX an Ansible playbook defined as this
(...)

- name: Set staging_ou
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    staging_ou: "OU=Linux Servers, OU=Servers, OU=ACME, OU=Units, DC=example, DC=xyz"

- name: Realm join into domain
  ansible.builtin.expect:
    command: /bin/bash -c 'realm join {{ domain }} --user={{ ad_join_user }} --computer-ou="{{ staging_ou }}"'
    responses:
      Password.*: "{{ ad_join_password }}"
    timeout: 120

(...)

I get the following error:

TASK [playbook_ad_join : Realm join into domain] **********************************
fatal: [myrhel9server]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "/bin/bash -c 'realm join example.xyz --user=svc-ansible --computer-ou="OU=Linux Servers, OU=Servers, OU=ACME, OU=Units, DC=example, DC=xyz"'", "delta": "0:00:00.152467", "end": "2024-11-13 11:45:09.577079", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2024-11-13 11:45:09.424612", "stdout": "realm: Already joined to this domain\r\nPlease check\r\n    https://red.ht/support_rhel_ad \r\nto get help for common issues.", "stdout_lines": ["realm: Already joined to this domain", "Please check", "    https://red.ht/support_rhel_ad ", "to get help for common issues."]}

A realm list confirms that the server is indeed in the example.xyz domain and returns the same output as when I ran the realm join ... command via shell.  However, I cannot su to AD users anymore: trying to do so returns an error

su: user johndoe@example.xyz does not exist or the user entry does not contain all the required fields

The link cited in the error message doesn't help.
What could be wrong?

EDIT 1: Running via shell the same command run via ansible, i.e.
/bin/bash -c 'realm join example.xyz (...) '

doesn't change anything with respect to running realm join example.xyz (...) (see top of post).
The other tasks in the playbook only modify a few config files:
/etc/krb5.conf
/etc/sssd/sssd.conf
/usr/local/bin/sss_ssh_authorizedkeys_ad
/etc/ssh/sshd_config 

and install some packages. These do not matter as the configuration already converged. I have removed a line which restarted the realmd daemon, since it could be the one causing the issue, but nothing changed.

Two questions:  (a) what happens when you type the same command being invoked by Ansible?  I.e., the full /bin/bash -c ..... and (b) what happens when you run a playbook that has only the two tasks you posted in this question, and nothing else?  (i.e., a simulation of what you type manually)

Thanks for your questions. I have answered them in the post.

Maybe the commands don't run as the same user? You could add the realm list command to a task right before the Realm join into domain task.

@dr_ that's good, but I asked what happens when you invoke a playbook containing just the two tasks you posted in the question.  It's not a thought experiment that can be satisfied by saying "the previous tasks don't matter", but a real experiment that must be performed to see the results.  Based on my own experience troubleshooting similar Ansible problems, it's necessary to actually perform the test.

I managed to pinpoint the problem by removing as many tasks as possible (as suggested by @SottoVoce in the comments). Eventually the playbook worked via a kludge -- by adding a  realm leave task (with ignore_errors: true) just before the realm join task.
